# How to call a python flask function which is call by a post request?

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, slack-api, slack

In below code,  `your_method` is called when `your_command` is executed in slack

```
from flask_slack import Slack
slack = Slack(app)
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=slack.dispatch)
@slack.command('your_command', token='your_token',
           team_id='your_team_id', methods=['POST'])
def your_method(**kwargs):
 text = kwargs.get('text')
 return text
```

How to call this `your_method` from another function in this python program.

Eg.

```
def print:
 a = your_method('hello','world')
```

This gives me error =>

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
return func(**kwargs)
File "sample.py", line 197
a = your_method('hello','world')
TypeError: your_method() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: Why can't you just import it and call it? What happens?

Comment: I didn't understand ?

Comment: It's a function. Why can't you call it like any other function, exactly as you show in the example?

Comment: this give me error =>

Comment: i have updated question with error.

Comment: Doesn't the error explain exactly what is going on? You're passing two positional arguments, `hello` and `world`, which the function is not expecting. This has nothing to do with Flask or posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the signature, tis function only accepts keyword arguments.

```
def your_method(**kwargs):
```

You call it with positional arguments.

```
your_method('hello', 'world')
```

You either need to change the signature

```
def your_method(*args, **kwargs)
```

or call it differently

```
your_method(something='hello', something_else='world')
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. Methods decorated with the `route` decorator cannot accept arguments passed in by you. View function arguments are reserved for route parameters, [like the following](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#routing):

```
@app.route('/user/<username>')
def show_user_profile(username):
    # show the user profile for that user
    return 'User %s' % username

@app.route('/post/<int:post_id>')
def show_post(post_id):
    # show the post with the given id, the id is an integer
    return 'Post %d' % post_id
```

Moreover, Flask does not want you to call on these methods directly, they are intended to be executed only in response to a request input from Flask.

A better practice would be to abstract whatever logic you are trying to do into another function.